# Optimization with Anylogic

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, anylogic

What is the optimization algorithm used by AnyLogic within the optimization experiment? And is it possible to change this algorithm to algorithms like Genetic Algorithm or even Nelder-Mead?
If this is possible, how could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that OptQuest uses a combination of scatter search and tabu search, though it is proprietary so there isn't clear information I could easily find. Here's one paper from 1997 that suggests this, though I don't know if OptQuest has changed.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.6463&rep=rep1&type=pdf

If you want to build your own optimizing, this is conceptually quite simple. I can see 2 broad ways to do this. One is to built it manually in a custom experiment. You can call individual experiments here and feed their results into an objective function before calling another simulation with updated results based on your custom optimizing algorithm. Another way would be to export your model as a runnable jar and do this outside of AnyLogic itself. Both options would require an AnyLogic pro license, though.

Actually, you can call one experiment from another without needing to build a custom experiment, so you might be able to do this without a pro license.

But regardless, you'd need to manually operationalize your new algorithm outside of the optimization experiment.